# Vim Ctrlp not parsing Ag (silver search) --ignore option correctly

Tags: vim, ctrlp

When using `ag` on the command line, like so:

`$> ag . --ignore="*node_modules/*/node_modules" -l --nocolor -f -U -g ""`

I am able to avoid searching through any node_modules directories more than one level deep in my node services, which is the desired behavior.

However, when I use the following in my vimrc, the node_modules directories more than one level deep are not ignored:

```
" Use The Silver Searcher https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher
if executable('ag')
  " Use Ag over Grep
  set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor

  " Use ag in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s --ignore="*node_modules/*/node_modules" -l --nocolor -f -U -g ""'
endif
```

How can I set up `ag` and `ctrlp` to correctly ignore those directories?
Not sure if I need to use a different syntax (like regex) or some other gotcha when transplanting to vimrc.

The reason I'm not putting this in the wildignore is that node_modules are ignored in my .gitignore, so I'm using the `-U` option to ignore any vcs files (thereby allowing `ag` to search node_modules) -- but this option also seems to bypass the wildignore.

Comment: Oh! The joys of layered abstractions!

Comment: This marks the first time I've found an answer inside a question ;) I removed the `--ignore` part due to `.agignore`. I removed `-U` so that ag would still use `.gitignore`. And I noticed that ag ignores hidden files by default.

Comment: I've reference this page here: https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/174

Answer (score 7):

Like you I do use both tools, but the way I ignore folders is different

For **Ag** I use the `.agignore` file, it has the same sintax as `.gitignore` and just like it, it can go in your home folder or project folder.

Not sure if that will solve your problem with **Ctrlp**, in any case it is quite fast already for me so I use the normal ignore variable like this:

```
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
  \ 'dir':  '\v[\/](doc|tmp|node_modules)',
  \ 'file': '\v\.(exe|so|dll)$',
  \ }
```

Comment: Ag [now recommends](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/commit/dd8e8396efc6f6be6ef3a730e700d6ef8da1d813) naming the file `.ignore` rather than `.agignore`. This allows other tools such as [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) to ignore the same files.

Comment: This was the most complete example I've found with the `.agignore`/`.ignore` https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/58#issuecomment-247017402